# Export R dataframes to multi-sheet Excel workbook without using external programming language

Tags: r, excel

First of all, I'm working with RStudio 0.98.1056.

I am writing a loop that produces several dataframes and I want to write each of them to a separate worksheet within an Excel workbook. (XLS and XLSX are both fine.) I know that there are several packages that do this, but they all seem to depend on other languages being present on the system -- the xlsx package depends on Java, as does the XLConnect package, and WriteXLS depends on Perl. I would like to avoid this because I want my code to be usable in contexts where installing an R package is trivial but installing support for another programming language is not.

So I have two questions:
1) Is there a package that duplicates this functionality using R only?
2) Are there serious obstacles to creating one?

Comment: If its ok to require Excel itself then RDCOMClient can be used to write Excel spreadsheets but as a general facilty for accessing COM it will be more work than using packages specialized for Excel.

Comment: What about [compiled C++ code](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [openxlsx](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html) package can write to separate sheets of an Excel file. Its only dependency is the [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) package. That's probably the most lightweight dependency of the contributed packages that can easily read and write Excel files.

The catch is that Rcpp requires a C++ compiler, but you can easily install that via [Rtools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) for Windows or [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) for Mac. Rcpp is a dependency for many contributed packages, so you might find that you already have it.

Comment: I appreciate this suggestion and I think it might be my best bet. I do already have Rtools, but the limitation I am working with here is that I want specific colleagues who do not have admin access to their machines to be able to use my package -- hence the desire for minimal overhead. Do you know offhand whether installing Rtools on a Windows machine requires admin privs? My feeling is that it doesn't but I am just not sure how to find out without trying.

Comment: I see what you mean, I think you might be right about Rtools needing admin privileges. Java is ubiquitous on Windows machine so unless you've got an unusual situation, you should be able to count on that dependency and use one of the java-based packages listed here: http://www.milanor.net/blog/?p=779 That page also lists a large number of other options, hopefully one will work for you!

Comment: Looks like "unusual situation" wins -- it's nowhere on my machine, for what I'm guessing is a reason of policy. I think convincing IT to install Rtools will be easier, so time to accept this answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Right, I see, that's quite a limitation. Something you might consider instead of Rtools is installing a VM like [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), then installing lubuntu and running RStudio in that. Then you can install whatever you like in the VM image without needing admin privileges, they just need to install the VM software once and then you have full control of the VM. A lightweight VM option is docker, see the [rocker project](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/wiki/Using-the-RStudio-image) for `R` images, including an RStudio image.